# map() does not return the correct form of my REST call result

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to do a REST call in my http.service.ts file. I am using Angular version 7 and RxJS. I want to get the cod value of json. I am doing a REST call to openweather API. When I am adding map() to get the desired value, it does not work. Only without map() it works. What am I missing?

My code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';


const API_URL = environment.apiURL;
const API_KEY = environment.apiKey;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getWeather() {
    return this.http.get(API_URL + '?q=London,us&APPID=' + API_KEY).pipe(map(r => { return r; })).subscribe(value => {
    }, catchError(error => {
      return throwError(error);
    }))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning any value from your `map()` projection function:

```
map(r => {
  this.cod = r.cod;
  return r;
}),
```

You don't need to use `map()` anyway. You can put this code to `subscribe`.

Comment: Hi! Why do I not need map()? Can u explain me when should I use map()?

Comment: Because you have to return the same value and you use `map()` only for side-effects. So it's better to put this to `subscribe()` or use `tap()` operator.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should return the observable and subscribe to it in the component that u want to use.
Also you are missing the return in the map operator, you dont need const cod, try avoid that global variables and use it inner class too.
This dont work

```
public getWeather() {
    return this.http.get(API_URL + '?q=London,us&APPID=' + API_KEY).pipe(map(r => { return r.cod; })).subscribe(value => {
    }, catchError(error => {
      return throwError(error);
    }))
  }
```

Good practice and subscribe in the component that u need and unsubscribe onDestroy.

```
public getWeather() {
    return this.http.get(API_URL + '?q=London,us&APPID=' + API_KEY).pipe(map(r => { return r.cod; }));
```

Here is an example you should use map 100%, check console.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vz2q82
I think your problem is where u call this method can you share it ?

Comment: Hi. U are right! I correct it. But it still does not working. It returns a Subscriber object.

Comment: it does not go inside there. smt goes wrong. Like this it worked: return this.http.get(API_URL + '?q=London,us&APPID=' + API_KEY).subscribe(json => console.log(json));

Comment: Should I not use map()? and why?

Comment: you should I leave an example hope it helps

Comment: can u do a chat discussion to discuss better?

Comment: i'm new in SO, so how we can do it ?